# How to save view fields into the models when, for instance, the form's save is clicked with Backbone.stickit

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I was using backbone.stickit so far for cases when the model should be updated immediately when the view's field was updated. But for several cases I found that it's more appropriate to update the model only when submit is pressed.

Stickit supports `events` so the events triggering override of the model can be defined. These events, however, are only input field specific.

Is it possible to trigger the override of the model for view events (like `clicked:submit`) ?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but you can use the [updateModel](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/#bindings/updatemodel) option to determine whether the view should update your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using custom event `saveClicked` triggered on input fields. In the bindings I set the field to stick to this custom event. For the form when save was clicked for every input field (also select, textarea,..) the `saveClicked` event is triggered.